# Java Apache Derby Database Restoration Error

Tags: apache, jpa

I am developing a JSF + JPA application with Netbeans & JavaDB. I copied the whole database folder when database is offline as instructed in [this link](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/adminguide/cadminhubbkup12677.html). When I copied the specific database sub-folder to another derby location or making the whole database folder as new Java Database Location in Netbeans Java Database, it gives a following error.

```
Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hr using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver(DERBY SQL error:SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE:XJ040, SQLERRMC:Failed to start database 'hr', see the next exception for details.:SQLSTATE:XSLANDatabase at D:\Data\PDHS\hr has an incompatible format with the current version of the software. The Database was created by or upgraded by version 10.8.).
```

How can I resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says:

```
The Database was created by or upgraded by version 10.8.
```

What version of Derby is the server running?

Comment: The Version of the destination computer is 10.5.3.0. So I will try to update java db and try again. Thank you.

Comment: The derby database running on destination computer was version 10.5. I updated the database and the issue was resolved. Thanks